# Trying to delete binary tree C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to delete a binary tree in C++, but I'm having a problem in that the size of the tree doesn't seem to change. This is the size function I'm using:

```
int BST::size(Node *& cur_root)
{
    if (cur_root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else { 
        return(size(cur_root->m_left) + 1 + size(cur_root->m_right));
    }
}
```

And this is the function I'm trying to use it in:

```
void BST::deletetree(Node *& cur_root)
{
    cout << "tree size: " << size() << endl;
    if (cur_root!=NULL)
    {
        deletetree(cur_root->m_left);
        deletetree(cur_root->m_right);
        delete cur_root;
        if(cur_root->m_left != NULL) {
            cur_root->m_left = NULL;
        }
        if(cur_root->m_right != NULL) {
            cur_root->m_right = NULL;
        }
        cur_root=NULL;
    }
}
```

For a tree size of three (1, 2, 3) my output is:

```
tree size: 3
tree size: 3
tree size: 3
tree size: 3
tree size: 3
tree size: 3
tree size: 3
```

Does anyone know why my size isn't going down with each deleted node?

EDIT: I removed the if statements, but the problem still persists

```
void BST::deletetree(Node *& cur_root)
{
    cout << "tree size: " << size() << endl;
    if (cur_root!=NULL)
    {
        deletetree(cur_root->m_left);
        deletetree(cur_root->m_right);
        delete cur_root;
        cur_root=NULL;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: This is my full code. BST.h:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BST
{
    public:
        BST();
        bool insert(string str) {return insert(str, m_root);}
        int size() {return size(m_root);}
        void deletetree() {return deletetree(m_root);}
    private:
        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(string value, Node *left = NULL, Node *right = NULL)
                {m_value = value; m_left = left; m_right = right;}
                string m_value;
                Node *m_left;
                Node *m_right;
        };
        Node *m_root;
        bool insert(string str, Node *& cur_root);
        int size(Node *& cur_root);
        void deletetree(Node *& cur_root);
};

#endif
```

BST.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <queue> 
#include <math.h> 
#include "bst.h"

BST::BST()
{
    m_root = NULL;
}

bool BST::insert(string str, Node *& cur_root)
{
    /*if (find(str) == true) {
        return false;
    }*/
    if (cur_root == NULL) {
        cur_root = new Node(str);
        return true;
    } else {
        if (cur_root->m_value < str) {
            return insert(str, cur_root->m_right);
        } else {
            return insert(str, cur_root->m_left);
        }
    }
}

int BST::size(Node *& cur_root)
{
    if (cur_root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else { 
        return(size(cur_root->m_left) + 1 + size(cur_root->m_right)); 
    }
}

void BST::deletetree(Node *& cur_root)
{
    cout << "tree size: " << size() << endl;
    if (cur_root!=NULL)
    {
        deletetree(cur_root->m_left);
        deletetree(cur_root->m_right);
        delete cur_root;
        cur_root=NULL;
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "bst.h"

int main()
{
    BST tree;
    tree.insert("1");
    tree.insert("2");
    tree.insert("3");
    tree.deletetree();
}
```

Ignore the commented section on insert. That's something I'm going to implement later when I have a find function.

Comment: That size() method you are printing the return value of can't be the same method that you posted the implementation of -- the method you posted takes one argument, but you're calling size() with no arguments.

Comment: In your delete function, you dereference `cur_root` right after it was deleted.

Comment: Everything after `delete cur_root;` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Except for `curr_root=NULL`.

Comment: size() calls for return size(m_root);

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the wrong behavior of your program

Comment: Also, provide some [MCVE] in your question

Answer (score 5):

Lets take a look at these line from your `deletetree` function:

```
delete cur_root;
if(cur_root->m_left != NULL) {
    cur_root->m_left = NULL;
}
if(cur_root->m_right != NULL) {
    cur_root->m_right = NULL;
}
```

The first line destructs the object pointed to by `cur_root`, and the rest of the lines dereference the pointer to access the now ***destructed*** object.

Dereferencing a pointer to a destructed object leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which makes all speculation about behavior useless.

The simple solution to this is to just not do the `if` checks, because they are simply not needed. All you need is the `delete cur_root` followed by `cur_root = nullptr`.

---

Now when we can see your full code, we can see that your insertion function doesn't create a tree. It creates a *list* (with the data inserted in the order you show).

When you insert `"1"` it becomes the root of the tree. Then when you insert `"2"` it becomes `m_root->m_right`. Then when you insert the `"3"` it becomes `m_root->m_right->m_right`. I haven't stepped through your code to know if it causes the `size` of the `deletetree` to behave wrong, but one of them do. You should use a debugger to find out which function causes your apparent problem.

Then you should think about the order you insert nodes into your tree. Or if your tree should become self-balanced and reorder the nodes on insertion.

Comment: I tried doing this, but the size remains at 3 constantly.

Comment: @ErikIngvoldsen Give us enough code to replicate your problem.

Comment: @ErikIngvoldsen Then it's time for you to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Something you really should have done from the start.

Comment: I...don't see what else I could include. There's the basic node object which contains the string and left/right right as well as the constructure for the tree (root = NULL), but this is basically the entire code.

Comment: @ErikIngvoldsen Please show us how you create the tree, and how you call the `deletetree` function. Preferably enough so we can ourselves copy the code and replicate the behavior.

Comment: OK I included the full code. Sorry, I did forget to mention the insert function since that's technically not complete (but working well enough for testing).

Comment: @ErikIngvoldsen With the data inserted in the order you show, you create a *list* and not a tree.

Comment: I know. After I've finished the delete function I'm going to build a balance function that looks for unbalanced trees (or lists) and re-balances them but first I need to figure out how to destroy the current tree so I can use the re balance function to make a new one.

Comment: @ErikIngvoldsen Then you need to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to figure out what and where the problem (if there is any!) is located and how it could possibly be fixed.